# filter values based on line items with data validation in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, phpexcel, export-to-excel, google-query-language

Data set 1

| P1 | Type | Size | Color | Material | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kurta Pyjamas | No | Sizeethnic_1 | Colorethnic_1 | Materialethnic_3 | Lengthethnic_1 |
| Dhotis | Typethnic_1 | No | Colorethnic_2 | Materialethnic_2 | No |
| Sherwani | No | No | Colorethnic_2 | No | Lengthethnic_2 |
| Men Pyjamas | Typeethnic_2 | No | Colorethnic_2 | No | No |
| Kurtas | No | Sizeethnic_2 | Colorethnic_1 | No | Lengthethnic_1 |
| Ethnic Jackets | No | No | Colorethnic_1 | No | No |

Data set 2

| Typethnic_1 | Typeethnic_2 | Sizeethnic_1 | Sizeethnic_2 | Colorethnic_1 | Colorethnic_2 | Materialethnic_3 | Materialethnic_2 | Lengthethnic_1 | Lengthethnic_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mundu | Churidar | XS | XS | Beige | Green | Blended | Silk Blend | Above Knee | Short |
| Regular Dhoti | Regular Pyjama | S | S | Black | Grey | Cotton | Velevt | Ankle Length | Medium |
| Patiala | M | M | Blue | Maroon | Dupion | Viscose Rayon |  |  |  |
| Jodhpuri | L | L | Brown | Multi |  | Wool |  |  |  |
| Harem | XL | XL | Copper | Mustard |  |  |  |  |  |
| XXL | XXL | Cream |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3XL | 3XL | Gold |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Problem Statement – Data set 1 has Named Ranges as drop down that holds values from Data set 2 where "Named Ranges" are created. I want to derive the values based on items from Column "P1" that sits within Data set 1.

What I am trying to Achieve – I aim to derive values based on items from Column "P1" that sits within Data set 1 and exclude "No" as values if they exist in these columns (P1, Type, Size, Color, Material, Length) for that particular line item ( Kurta Pyjamas, Dhotis, Sherwani, Men Pyjamas, Kurtas, Ethinic Jackets).

Expected result:

You can also see the small video of the desired output:

https://www.loom.com/share/4bc25874003448cc91fc3dc9a69c4a63

[image]

Selecting Dhoti

[image]

I am also posting an example google sheet with data set.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18guAXXjWIMDQilX8Z0Y4_Avogjs2ESMbrZY7Sb9TaxE/edit?usp=sharing

Any thoughts or solution will be welcome.

Comment: `What I am trying to do here` - I don't see any effort, did you forget to include your code in a question?

Comment: I have tried many codes available online but unable to combine the data validation and column select in query or app script.

Comment: Please add the table as text, not as an image. Find out how to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18guAXXjWIMDQilX8Z0Y4_Avogjs2ESMbrZY7Sb9TaxE/edit?usp=sharing you can access the table here

Comment: Many of us are starting to reject the notion of following links to your google account because they expose both of our emails and I also find the links to shared drives are difficult to remove. So if you wish to improve you chances to get an answer you might consider images and tables for data.

Comment: I have updated the images to Table.

Comment: Please post your code into the question

Comment: What is it that you want downloaded and where does it get downloaded to.

Comment: I am trying to download the columns where the name range value is mentioned with data validation based on name range values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240531/discussion-between-sameer-farooqui-and-cooper).

Comment: @cooper can you help.

Comment: I probably could help if I understood what you wanted

Comment: @Cooper : I have updated the description and also tried to recreate the problem with a small video, please see if you can help here

Comment: Sorry but I will not follow links to off site resources including google accounts.

Comment: You can post simple gif videos on SO to help explain some fine points.  Of course no audio.   Your question still suffers from the weakness of your having not attempted any code yourself and it's still difficult to imagine what the User Interface might look like.

Comment: @Cooper : I have added the Gif file of the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Providing Data Validation using onEdit Trigger

```
function loadObjectsAndCreateProductDropDown() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const psh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const [ph, ...prds] = sh.getRange(1, 1, 10, 6).getValues().filter(r => r[0]);
  const [ch, ...chcs] = sh.getRange(11, 1, 10, 10).getValues().filter(r => r.join());
  let pidx = {};
  ph.forEach((h, i) => { pidx[h] = i });
  let prd = { pA: [] };
  prds.forEach(r => {
    if (!prd.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      prd[r[0]] = { type: r[pidx['Type']], size: r[pidx['Size']], color: r[pidx['Color']], material: r[pidx['Material']], length: r[pidx['Length']] };
      prd.pA.push(r[0]);
    }
  });
  let cidx = {};
  let chc = {};
  ch.forEach((h, i) => { cidx[h] = i; chc[h] = [] });
  chcs.forEach(r => {
    r.forEach((c, i) => {
      if (c && c.length > 0) chc[ch[i]].push(c)
    })
  })
  const ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  ps.setProperty('product_matrix', JSON.stringify(prd));
  ps.setProperty('product_choices', JSON.stringify(chc));
  Logger.log(ps.getProperty('product_matrix'));
  Logger.log(ps.getProperty('product_choices'));
  psh.getRange('A2').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(prd.pA).build());
}

//I chose to use an installable dropdown.  I'm not sure if it's needed.  Its up to you.

function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('flag1');
    sh.getRange('C2:G2').clearDataValidations();
    let ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    let prodObj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty('product_matrix'));//recovering objects from PropertiesService
    let choiObj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty('product_choices'));
    let hA = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat();
    let col = {};
    hA.forEach((h, i) => { col[h.toLowerCase()] = i + 1 });
    ["type", "size", "color", "material", "length"].forEach(c => {
      if (choiObj[prodObj[e.value][c]]) {
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, col[c]).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(choiObj[prodObj[e.value][c]]).build());
      }
    })
  }
}
```

You could try it this way but I'm guessing you want something different.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('flag1');
    sh.getRange('C2:G2').clearDataValidations();
    let ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    let prodObj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty('product_matrix'));//recovering objects from PropertiesService
    let choiObj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty('product_choices'));
    let hA = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat();
    let col = {};
    hA.forEach((h, i) => { col[h.toLowerCase()] = i + 1 });
    ["type", "size", "color", "material", "length"].forEach(c => {
      if (choiObj[prodObj[e.value][c]]) {
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, col[c]).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(choiObj[prodObj[e.value][c]]).build()).offset(-1,0).setFontColor('#000000');
      } else {
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, col[c]).offset(-1,0).setFontColor('#ffffff');
      }
    })
  }
}
```

This version actually hides the columns too

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('flag1');
    sh.getRange('C2:G2').clearDataValidations();
    let ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    let prodObj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty('product_matrix'));//recovering objects from PropertiesService
    let choiObj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty('product_choices'));
    let hA = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat();
    let col = {};
    hA.forEach((h, i) => { col[h.toLowerCase()] = i + 1 });
    ["type", "size", "color", "material", "length"].forEach(c => {
      if (choiObj[prodObj[e.value][c]]) {
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, col[c]).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(choiObj[prodObj[e.value][c]]).build()).offset(-1,0).setFontColor('#000000');
        sh.showColumns(col[c])
      } else {
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, col[c]).offset(-1,0).setFontColor('#ffffff');
        sh.hideColumns(col[c]);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Here's what the last version looks like:

[image]

This is my Sheet0:

| P1 | Type | Size | Color | Material | Length |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kurta Pyjamas |  | Sizeethnic_1 | Colorethnic_1 | Materialethnic_3 | Lengthethnic_1 |  |  |  |  |
| Dhotis | Typethnic_1 |  | Colorethnic_2 | Materialethnic_2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Sherwani |  |  | Colorethnic_2 |  | Lengthethnic_2 |  |  |  |  |
| Men Pyjamas | Typeethnic_2 |  | Colorethnic_2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Kurtas |  | Sizeethnic_2 | Colorethnic_1 |  | Lengthethnic_1 |  |  |  |  |
| Ethnic Jackets |  |  | Colorethnic_1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Typethnic_1 | Typeethnic_2 | Sizeethnic_1 | Sizeethnic_2 | Colorethnic_1 | Colorethnic_2 | Materialethnic_3 | Materialethnic_2 | Lengthethnic_1 | Lengthethnic_2 |
| Mundu | Churidar | XS | XS | Beige | Green | Blended | Silk Blend | Above Knee | Short |
| Regular Dhoti | Regular Pyjama | S | S | Black | Grey | Cotton | Velevt | Ankle Length | Medium |
| Patiala | M | M | Blue | Maroon | Dupion | Viscose Rayon |  |  |  |
| Jodhpuri | L | L | Brown | Multi |  | Wool |  |  |  |
| Harem | XL | XL | Copper | Mustard |  |  |  |  |  |
| XXL | XXL | Cream |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3XL | 3XL | Gold |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Appreciate your help, If I go by the script flow first it should check which columns are applicable for respective product selection, second deletes the column which are not applicable, third rearrange the applicable columns and create the validation

Comment: I dont understand your last comment

Comment: For e.g. if i am selecting kurtas the type and material column is not applicable, it should delete the "not applicable" columns and only retain the applicable columns with validation

Comment: I chose not to do it that way but you may do it however you wish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241117/discussion-between-sameer-farooqui-and-cooper).